# Geometry as a Group Action

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

At 38:45 in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w30xG_vGwoc) by Thurston he defines a geometry as a an action by a group $G$ on a simply connected topological space $X$ such that the action is transitive and the stabilizer of a point $x\in X$ is compact.  How would you construct Euclidean and or spherical geometry using Thurston's definition?

Comment: I think you left out analytic. For Euclidean, $X$ is the plane and $G$ is the group of congruence transformations. For spherical, $X$ is the two-sphere $G$ is $SO(3)$. Read his notes, you can download them from MSRI.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman OK thanks.  I'll take a look.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman In what branch of mathematics would they introduce the definition of a geometry in this way?  I'd like to get a good book on the subject.

Comment: Low dimensional topology. You can download Thurston’s notes from MSRI. The approach goes back to the 19th century. The section with this definition is: http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/3.pdf

Comment: Here is an undergraduate introduction: Low-Dimensional Geometry (Student Mathematical Library: IAS/Park City Mathematical Subseries) https://www.amazon.com/dp/082184816X/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_-YkxCbJ7WQR22